# Group By OrgName but rollup by TotalCount

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I would like to use the code below to group results by OrgName but rollup the count using TotalCount

Results would look similar to the screenshot below:(sorry I had to redact information due to confidentiality agreement).

[image]

The Orgname is grouped correctly. However, I am having a little troubling rolling up totalCount.

Thanks

```
WITH
ctePreAgg AS
(
 SELECT (ElectionName + ' - ' + CAST(ClosingDate AS VARCHAR(12))) electionName, CASE WHEN Position='Member' THEN '' ELSE Position END As Position, CASE WHEN c.CurrentOfficeHolder='Incumbent' THEN CandidateName + '('+ c.CurrentOfficeHolder + ')' ELSE CandidateName END As CandidateName , c.PositionId,COUNT(*) TotalVotes 
   FROM Candidates c 
   JOIN Positions p ON c.PositionId = p.PositionId
   JOIN Elections e on c.ElectionId = e.ElectionId
  WHERE c.ElectionId IN (1,2,3)
  GROUP BY Position, CandidateId, CandidateName,c.PositionId,CurrentOfficeHolder,AnswerType,ElectionName, ClosingDate
)

  SELECT [OrgName] = CASE WHEN GROUPING(mh.PositionId) = 0 THEN MAX(mh.Position)  ELSE mh.ElectionName END
        ,Names = CASE WHEN GROUPING(mh.PositionId) = 0 THEN MAX(mh.CandidateName)    ELSE '' END
        ,PositionId    = CASE WHEN GROUPING(mh.PositionId) = 0 THEN mh.PositionId   ELSE '' END
        ,TotalCount = CASE WHEN GROUPING(mh.PositionId) = 0 THEN COUNT(*) ELSE '' END
  FROM  ctePreAgg mh
  GROUP BY ElectionName,PositionId WITH ROLLUP
  HAVING GROUPING(mh.ElectionName) = 0
  ORDER BY mh.ElectionName, GROUPING(mh.PositionId) DESC, mh.PositionID;
```

Comment: Unfortunately given your limitations on what you can display it isn't very clear what you are trying to do, the `positionID` column can be easily removed by either removing the line defining it or commenting it out. What do you mean by "I am having a little troubling rolling up totalCount", I personally am not familiar with what your intended behaviour is from "rolling up". What have you already tried? Could you put dummy data into your question to make it clearer what is being returned? Or even create a dummy [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: @talegna, Are you serious about `What have you tried` or are you trying to score some cheap points, with ALL due respect?`

I posted the code I have written so far and I have also posted a screenshot of exactly what the results of my query shows so far.

So, I am a bit confused by your comments.

Comment: I can assure you that I didn't comment to "score points" I was hoping to be able to help and was putting a suggestion down to hopefully prevent others voting down & clarify your requirements. You've not stated what you have tried to resolve the problem, putting code up here is helpful for allowing people to come up with resolutions however the above doesn't demonstrate. A redacted screenshot doesn't really provide detail on the data format etc. You said "please remove positionId as Column name completely?" this could mean that you may not even understand the SQL used to select the results.

Comment: @talegna, `You said "please remove positionId as Column name completely?" `

You have got a good point there. I will remove that statement because the code is mine.